# android add shadow below view

Tags: android, shadow

i just try to add shadow to my `LinearLayout` to make my View act like its over other view just like this image `facebook messenger`

[image]

i try this xml as background from my View but its seems like a line not shadow

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient android:startColor="@color/black_alpha_12" 
android:endColor="@android:color/transparent" android:angle="90.0" />
</shape>
```

and i try many xml code in stackoverflow no one help me to make shadow like what i want

Comment: **`getSupportActionBar().setElevation(10);`**

Comment: its a View not `ActionBar`

Comment: the selected are called **`ActionBar`**

Comment: but in my app i made an `LinearLayout` as `ActionBar `
did this will work `View.setElevation(10);` ?

Comment: @Nilu don't answer the question in the comments. You can get rep if you make a answer.

Comment: @MedoZeus share xml code for `LinearLayout as ActionBar `

Comment: @GrantGarrison i know that BTW thanks

Comment: @Nilu i add its to View and its work thank you :D

Comment: @MedoZeus happy to help you

Comment: In your case Just use [AppBar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html) with toolBar it comes with elevation by default.

Comment: @Nilu must wait 4 minute to accept :)

Comment: @ADM thank for your advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(10);
```

> But as per Your Above Comment `in my app i made an LinearLayout as ActionBar did this will work`

Than Use

```
YourView.setElevation(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> getSupportActionBar().setElevation(10);

Another reference i had answered here first [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675791/how-to-add-bottom-shadow-to-tab-layout)

Hope this may helps you

Answer (score 0):

HI for shadow effect you can you cardview or view.setElevation(10); both will work.

ref-[How to add shadow on CardView aligned to bottom of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615468/how-to-add-shadow-on-cardview-aligned-to-bottom-of-parent)

ref-https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#

Answer (score 0):

Attribute elevation is only used in API level 21 and higher
For example, some tags can be unused too, such as the new  element in layouts introduced in API 21.

Set the elevation property in xml to say 10dp or 8dp 
android:elevation="10dp"

Answer (score -1):

Use `<layer-list>` for set background of view.
Like this

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/tv_item"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/keyboard_btn_bg"
    />
```

**keyboard_btn_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="130dp"
                android:height="25dp" />
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="#20000000" />
            <solid android:color="#20000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="160dp"
                android:height="25dp" />
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <padding
                android:top="8dp"
                android:bottom="8dp"
                android:left="8dp"
                android:right="8dp"
                />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#808080" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
```