# How to show bottom shadow in android?

Tags: android

how to create this type of layout in android look like image

[image]:

Comment: did you try to use `CardView` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android View shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211870/android-view-shadow)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `MaterialCardView` and use `cardElevation`

add this in gradle file to use `material components`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
```

style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

in your xml

```
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:strokeWidth="1dp"
            app:strokeColor="@color/stroke_color"
            app:cardElevation="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            //add some view

        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: You can also set elevation programmatically. Definitely the best answer.

Comment: @Jaydeep chatrola  MaterialCardView not resolve or not shown in xml

Comment: Add the written dependency to your Gradle.

Comment: @DarshiDomadiya use material theme

Comment: @DarshiDomadiya increase card elevation as per your need

Comment: @DarshiDomadiya tamaru swagat che

Answer (score 1):

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/maincard"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_250sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_12sdp"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use `cardView` and add `onclick` func to act as a button

Inside the `cardView`, you need to customize the layout of `TextView`, `ImageView` and other UI you want.

https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-cardview

https://material.io/develop/android/components/cards/

For button shadow, I guess `cardView` can add shadow too

[How to add shadow on CardView aligned to bottom of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615468/how-to-add-shadow-on-cardview-aligned-to-bottom-of-parent)

Answer (score 0):

Did u try: android:elevation="3dp" in view xml? let try.

Hope this help!